# Buscar primeiro nome no campo mysql antes do espaço MYSQL

Tags: mysql

Tenho que procurar por uma data em um campo do mysql, mas os caras tinham colocado pra guardar assim "2016-02-21 14:02:01" eu só preciso da data dali , como posso verificar no select a data que eu quero comparando com aquela data?

Answer (score 2):

`select date(nomedacoluna) from minhatabela`

mais detalhes em [mysql date()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date)

Answer (score 2):

Como o **@rray** já respondeu, você pode fazer um select formatando o campo, mas isso pode tirar um pouco da performance.

Para uma solução mais performática, recomendo utilizar uma cláusula `BETWEEN` da seguinte forma:

```
SELECT * FROM tabela WHERE campo BETWEEN '2016-02-21 00:00:00' AND '2016-02-21 23:59:59'
```

Answer (score 1):

Pode converter uma coluna do tipo datetime em date apenas usando `cast()`. Ou formatando a data com `date_format()`

```
SELECT * FROM tabela WHERE CAST(campo as date) = '2016-02-21'
```

ou

```
SELECT * FROM tabela WHERE date_format(campo,'%Y-%m-%d) = '2016-02-21'
```

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda